# Adding a new field to the N most reset docs by day in MongoDB 4.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents with scheme :

```
{ _id: ObjectId, userId: ObjectId, marker: string, datetime: Date, etc... }
```

This is a collection of markers (`marker`) bounded to a user (`userId`). The date of bound is stored in `datetime` field.

Each day user can receive an arbitrary number of markers.

When I'm fetching data from this collection, I need to add an extra field called `allowed` of type `boolean` and this field have to be `true` only if this record is in the N most resent records for calendar day for a user.

For example, if initial collection looks like this and **N == 2** :

```
{_id: ..., userId: "a", marker: "m1", datetime: "2020-01-01.10:00"}
{_id: ..., userId: "a", marker: "m2", datetime: "2020-01-02.10:00"}
{_id: ..., userId: "a", marker: "m3", datetime: "2020-01-02.11:00"}
{_id: ..., userId: "a", marker: "m4", datetime: "2020-01-02.12:00"}
{_id: ..., userId: "a", marker: "m5", datetime: "2020-01-02.13:00"}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m1", datetime: "2020-01-01.10:00"}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m2", datetime: "2020-01-01.11:00"}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m3", datetime: "2020-01-01.13:00"}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m4", datetime: "2020-01-02.11:00"}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m5", datetime: "2020-01-02.12:00"}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m6", datetime: "2020-01-03.10:00"}
```

Then final result should look like this:

```
{_id: ..., userId: "a", marker: "m1", datetime: "2020-01-01.10:00", allowed: true}
{_id: ..., userId: "a", marker: "m2", datetime: "2020-01-02.10:00", allowed: true}
{_id: ..., userId: "a", marker: "m3", datetime: "2020-01-02.11:00", allowed: true}
{_id: ..., userId: "a", marker: "m4", datetime: "2020-01-02.12:00", allowed: false}
{_id: ..., userId: "a", marker: "m5", datetime: "2020-01-02.13:00", allowed: false}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m1", datetime: "2020-01-01.10:00", allowed: true}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m2", datetime: "2020-01-01.11:00", allowed: true}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m3", datetime: "2020-01-01.13:00", allowed: false}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m4", datetime: "2020-01-02.11:00", allowed: true}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m5", datetime: "2020-01-02.12:00", allowed: true}
{_id: ..., userId: "b", marker: "m6", datetime: "2020-01-03.10:00", allowed: true}
```

I'm using MongoDB 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below queries :

**Query 1:**

```
 db.markers.aggregate([
    /** group docs based on userId & date(2020-01-01), push all matched docs to data */
    { $group: { _id: { userId: '$userId', datetime: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ["$datetime", "."] }, 0] } }, data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
    /** Re-forming data field with added new field allowed for only docs where criteria is met */
    {
        $addFields: {
            data: {
                $map:
                {
                    input: "$data",
                    as: "each",
                    /** conditional check to add new field on only docs which are 0 & 1 position of array */
                    in: { $cond: [{ $lte: [{ $indexOfArray: ["$data", '$$each'] }, 1] }, { $mergeObjects: ['$$each', { allowed: true }] }, { $mergeObjects: ['$$each', { allowed: false }] }] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    /** unwind data */
    { $unwind: '$data' },
    /** making data object as root level doc */
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }])
```

**Query 2:**

```
db.markers.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: { userId: '$userId', datetime: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ["$datetime", "."] }, 0] } }, data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } }, {
        $addFields: {
            data: {
                $map:
                {
                    input: "$data",
                    as: "each",
                    in: {
                        $cond: [{
                            $or: [{ $eq: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$data", -1] }, '$$each'] }, { $eq: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$data", -2] }, '$$each'] }]
                        },
                        { $mergeObjects: ['$$each', { allowed: true }] },
                        { $mergeObjects: ['$$each', { allowed: false }] }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, { $unwind: '$data' }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }])
```

**Query1** will work & get you the results, but assuming data given in question is sample data & in real-time when you look at collection `userId: "a", marker: "m5"` will be first document as if this collection has continuous data writes then latest document would will have latest `data time`, So **Query1**'s index 0 or 1 will not work, but here **Query2** would work. You can use **Query1** if markers collection has exactly same ordered data as given in question.

**Note :** In **Query2** - We can use same logic of **Query1** (which is to check indexes(0,1)) instead of object comparison but this can be applicable only if we've `$sort` of `dateTime` field as first stage, And I haven't gone that route is because sorting on a whole collection's data on a field would not be efficient than this.